# Extracting PEM from Xamarin Keystore File

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play, google-play-console

I need to provide a PEM file to Google so that they can re-key the app signing and I can publish updates to the app. They have their key in Google Console, but my private key was corrupted by Xamarin. Google will accept a new PEM file from my new keystore to reconnect them so that I may distribute again.

However, Xamarin has its own proprietary .keystore file format. I've used keytool to extract a PEM from a Java jks.

How can I get the PEM to send to Google from a Xamarin .keystore file?

Comment: AFAIK the Xamarin keystore file is not "proprietary" and is generated by the same Android SDK tools.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=windows

Comment: Is there a keytool command (or other way) to extract the PEM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to export a PEM like so:

```
keytool -export -rfc -alias your-alias -file play-store.pem -keystore your.keystore
```